# How does Distinct() work on object list?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Atish"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Dipongkor"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Atish"
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(people.Distinct().Count());
```

Why is the output **3**?

Why is it not **2**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default equality comparer for reference types is reference equality, which only returns `true` if two object references point to the *same* instance (i.e. were created via a single `new` statement). This is different than for value types, which test for value equality, and would return `true` if all their data fields are equal (like the two in your case). More info: [Equality Comparisons (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd183752.aspx).

If you want to alter this behaviour, then you need to implement the generic [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface on your type such that it compares the instances' properties for equality. The `Distinct` operator would subsequently automatically pick this implementation up and yield the expected results.

**Edit**: Here's a sample implementation of `IEquatable<Person>` for your class:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other) ||
            this.Id == other.Id &&
            this.Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = this.Id.GetHashCode();
        if (this.Name != null)
            hash ^= this.Name.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

From the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) on overriding the `==` and `!=` operators (emphasis added):

> By default, the operator `==` tests for reference equality by determining whether two references indicate the same object. Therefore, reference types do not have to implement operator `==` in order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, that is, the data that is contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator `==` to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. **It is not a good idea to override operator `==` in non-immutable types.**

Comment: Would you please give an example of IEquatable<T> with code by editing your answer? Or any link will be enough for me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's because you haven't overriden equality in your class. Right now, when you use distinct, it checks for reference equality. To change this, you need to override a fair few things: the `operator==`, `Equals()`, and for best results `GetHashCode()`.

This is how I'd do it:

```
public static bool operator ==(Person one, Person two)
{
    return one.Id == two.Id && one.Name == two.Name;
}
public static override bool Equals(Person one, Person two)
{
    return one == two;
}
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is Person && ((Person)obj) == this;
}
public bool Equals(Person other)
{
    return other == this;
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return 17 * Id * 31 * Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Also, you could implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface (I have done above, all you need is to make sure that you add `: IEquatable<Person>` at the end of your class header (`class Person` etc.)) and then that will be implemented.

Comment: Is overriding really the best way to go?
Why not just implement IEquatable?

Comment: @Kippie Because it'd usually be expected to be overriden.